# RxJava2 .startWith(..) doesn't work

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have `Observable` what emit some `String`:

```
List<String> list = // size this list is 5
Observable o1 = Observable.fromArray(list.toArray());
```

and another one what emit one object per 10 second:

```
Observable intervalObservable = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I want to create Observable what every 10 second will emit every item from `o1`, so I did:

```
Observable change2tervalToString = intervalObservable.map(new Function() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(Object o) throws Exception {
            return "STARTER!";
        }
    });

Observable per10sec = o1.startWith(change2tervalToString);
```

If I `.subscribe()` to `per10sec` it doesn't emit something like:

```
"STARTER", "ITEM_FROM_LIST1", "ITEM_FROM_LIST2", "ITEM_FROM_LIST3"...
```

but only (every 10 second):

```
"STARTER"
```

I want to achive something like this:

```
"STARTER", "ITEM_FROM_LIST1", "ITEM_FROM_LIST2", "ITEM_FROM_LIST3"...
....
....
 10 sec
....
....
"STARTER", "ITEM_FROM_LIST1", "ITEM_FROM_LIST2", "ITEM_FROM_LIST3"...
....
....
....
```

Comment: of course it works, you just misunderstood what it actually does

Comment: @TimCastelijns what do you mean?

Comment: @MateuszCieplak see [documentation on StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<String> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                return Observable.fromIterable(list);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. But why `.startWith(...)` doesn't? When I change `per10sec = o1.startWith(change2tervalToString);` to `per10sec = o1.startWith("STARTER");` it works but iterate only once. So it should works with `startWith`

Comment: If you read StartWith's documentation:`If you want an Observable to emit a specific sequence of items before it begins emitting the items normally expected from it, apply the StartWith operator to it.`
It only emit ones. Go through each of the operators doc [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) and you will be able to figure out what is wrong

Comment: @MateuszCieplak, `startWith` + `interval` doesn't combine together to mean `repeat`. See [RxJava.StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

Comment: Super. Thank you for help understand me this.

Answer (score 4):

Try startWithItem() for rxjava3

Answer (score 0):

Let's arrive at the conclusion from the other side.

You want to have:

```
"STARTER", "ListItem1", "ListItem2"...
```

This means:

```
Observable listItems = Observable.from(list.toArray());
Observable starter = Observable.just("STARTER");

Observable line = listItems.startWith(starter); // this will give you a line you want to emit
```

Then, you want to emit the line every 10 seconds. This means:

```
Observable timer = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// createLine() is the snippet from above.
Observable sequence = timer.flatMap(repetition -> createLine(list));
```

Also, assuming you don't want to wait 10 seconds before receiving first "line", you would want to start with a line:

```
sequence.startWith(createLine(list)); // first time emit immediately.
```

Documentation:

- [Just](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html)
- [From](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html)
- [StartWith](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)
- [Interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html)
- [FlatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)